# If a Borel measurable $f\ge 0$ satisfies $\int_{E}fdm<\infty$ for Borel $E$s with $m(E)<1$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}n\cdot m(\{f\ge n\})=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If a Borel measurable nonnegative $f$ satisfies $\int_{E}fdm<\infty$ for Lebesgue measurable sets $E$ with $m(E)<1$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}n\cdot m(\{f\ge n\})=0$.

I saw similar questions here, but they assumed that either $\int_{X}f<\infty$ or that $|\int_{E}f|<1$ for $m(E)<1$.

Here, however, the problem being that $\int_{E}fdm$ is finite but can be as big as it can, I am not sure if the same arguments work. Following @Matija's reasoning, I let $g(x)=n\chi_{A}$, where $A={x:f(x)=\infty}$, which means $g_n(x)\le f(x)$. Hence: $\int_{E}n\chi_{A}dm\le \int_{E}{}fdm<\infty$  so $\le n.m(A\cap E)$, but I don't know how to keep from here. This is a bit confusing, and dominated convergence dont seem to apply leaving it in that form. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am asked to show that the limit is $0$. The function is Borel measurable. Could there be something wrong with the data?

Comment: I was remiss stating that $\int_{E}f\le \infty$ where $E$ is Borel set whose Lebesgue measure is smaller than 1. Is it still wrong?

Comment: I have been trying to solve it for hours, it is an example of a test, this is not typical. Is there a minimal requirement for the conclusion to follow?

Comment: Is $\{f\geqslant n\} = \{x \in E: f(x) \geqslant n\}$?

Comment: $\{f\ge n\}$ stands for $\{x:f\ge n\}$... I didn't notice I was using an shortcut

Comment: So you can't use $$n\, m(\{f\geqslant n\}) \leqslant \int_{\{f\geqslant n\}}f \leqslant \int_E f < \infty,$$

Comment: If $\{f \geqslant n\} \subset E$ then it is easy.

Comment: Because: $1_{A}n\le f$ everywhere (almost),, so, $\int_{f\ge n}f \ge n\int_{f\ge n}1=nm{f\ge}n$, isn't it?

Comment: What scares me is that for some $E$ it might be true, but all it seems to mean is that $E\cap A=\emptyset$. Maybe $\Bbb{R}$ should be partitioned to intervals of halves?

Comment: The question is not worded clearly.  Is this condition supposed to hold "for all" $E$ with $m(E)<1$?  Or is one to assume $E$ is given and is the domain of the function?

Comment: In general there is much value in concise descriptors such as "for all" and "for some" and "there exists" and "$f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$"  (functions are supposed to have domains).

Comment: Check my edit:
It is given that on **Borel** measureable sets whose Lebesgue volume is smaller than $1$ the integral is finite

Comment: I'll ask my Professor for the sake of sorting it out, though I really doubt that he had made an error.

Comment: Isn't it obviously false? Consider for example, $f(x)=x^2$. Then for any set of finite measure $E$, the integral $\int_E f<\infty$ but $n|\{f\ge n\}|=\infty$ for all $n$.

Comment: $E=\cup_n (n,n+\frac 1 {n^{2}})$ has finite measure and integral of $x^{2}$ over it is infinity. @WhoKnowsWho

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, I see! Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all observe that $|\{f=\infty\}|=0$. If it has a positive measure, you can find a subset of measure less than $1$ and integrate over it.

We'll now argue by contradiction. Suppose $\limsup n|\{f\ge n\}|=2\delta>0$. Therefore, there exists a sequence $n_k\to \infty$ such that $|\{f\ge n_k\}|\ge \frac{\delta}{n_k}$. After passing to a subsequence we may assume that $|\{n_k\le f\le n_{k+1}\}|\ge \frac{\delta}{2n_k}$ and moreover, we can also assume that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n_k}<\frac{10}{\delta}$.

For each $k$, choose a subset $B_{n_k}\subseteq \{n_k\le f\le n_{k+1}\}$ such that $\frac{\delta}{20n_k}\leq |B_{n_k}|\le \frac{\delta}{10n_k}$. Define $E:=\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_{n_k}$ and note that $|E|<1$. But, we have $$\int_E f\;dm \geq \frac{\delta}{20}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n_k}n_k=\infty.$$
This contradicts the assumption on $f$ and hence we conclude the result!

Answer (score 1):

Here an answer assuming that $m(\{x: f(x)>\epsilon\}) <\infty$ for some $\epsilon >0$.

Suppose the conclusion fails. There exists an increasing sequence $(n_k)$ and $r>0$ such that $m(\{x: f(x)>n_k\})>\frac r {n_k}$ for all $k$. Note that  $m(\{x: f(x)>t )\to 0$ as $ t \to \infty$. [This is where my assumption is needed]. By going to  subsequence , if necessary, we may suppose $m(\{x: f(x)>n_k) <\frac 1 {2^{k}}$. Now $\sum _k m(\{x: f(x)>n_k) <\infty$. So for  $N$ sufficiently large $\sum\limits_{k=N}^{\infty} m(\{x: f(x)>n_k)<1$ . Let $E_N=\bigcup_{k>N} \{x: f(x)>n_k\}$. Then $m(E)<1$. ALso, $\int_{E_N} f \geq \int_{\{x: f(x)>n_k\}}f >n_km({\{x: f(x)>n_k\}}>r$ However, $E_N$ decreases to $E\equiv \lim \sup  \{x: f(x)>n_k\}$ and $m(E)=0$. Since $f$ is integrable ion $E_N$ for  $N$ sufficiently large  we must have$\int_{E_N}f \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$. We have reached  a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Continuity from above doesn't necessarily apply to a sequence of measurable sets $\{F_j\}_1^\infty$ if we don't assume $m(F_n)<\infty$ for some $n \geq 1$.

As for a counterexample:

Consider $$f(x):=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \log(n)\chi_{\left[n-2, n-2+(n\log(n))^{-1}\right]}(x)$$

Notice we have $m(\{x:f(x) \geq n\})=\sum_{k=\lceil e^n \rceil}^\infty \frac{1}{k\log(k)}=\infty$ for each fixed positive integer $n$ BUT $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \{x:f(x) \geq n\} = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

This is **just** an attempt in the absence of possibility of the statement above being correct:

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$ and $A=\{x:f(x)=\infty\}$.

Also  $A_n=\{x:f(x)\ge n\}$.
Assume that there exists no $M$ for which $\{f\ge M\}<\infty$, and consider $F_n=\bigcap_{k=0}^{n}\{f\ge k\}$. So $F=\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty}\{f\ge n\}=\{x:f(x)=\infty\}$ is of infinite measure and so are $\{f\ge n\}$.

Now let  $E\in B(\Bbb{R})$ with $m(E)<1$. So $$\infty>\int_{E}fdm=\int_{E\cap F_n}fdm+\int_{E\cap {F_n}^c}fdm\ge \int_{E\cap F_n}fdm\ge n\cdot m(E\cap \{f\ge n\})$$ and as $n\to \infty$, $m(E\cap \{f\ge n\})\to 0$ which means $\{f\ge n\}$ restricted to any $E$ with $m(E)<1$ is null. In particular, $\int_{E\cap F}fdm<\infty$, and therefore $E\cap F=\emptyset$ for $E$ with $m(E)<1$, hence $F\cap(\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb{Z}}{(n, n+{1\over 2}]\cup((n+{1\over 2},n]})=\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb{Z}}(({F\cap(n, n+{1\over 2}])\cup(F\cap(n+{1\over 2},n]}))$ which is a countable collection of null sets which means $F$ is null, contradicting the assumption above. Let $M$ be such that $\{f\ge M\}<\infty$.
I still try to figure out how to get from here, but the statement is correct according to my TA.